# How do you load an iframe in WKWebView locally?

Tags: html, swift, iframe, wkwebview

I am trying to implement WKWebView to display the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Appendix B1 - GFACN33 (East coast)</title>
  <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <article class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <iframe src="../../content/footer.html"></iframe>
  </footer>
  <script src="../../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../js/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=default.js"></script>
  <script src="../../js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Only the **iframe** has troubles loading and throws the following error:

> Received an unexpected URL from the web process: 'file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/160FB6DE-E1E2-47AD-A715-202EF5C5C1FB/SampleApp.app/Bookshelf/Books/BookName/content/footer.html'
>   2018-04-16 18:57:16.049559-0700 SampleApp[5047:5710785] Received an invalid message "WebPageProxy.DecidePolicyForNavigationAction" from the web process.
>
> Received an invalid message "WebPageProxy.DecidePolicyForNavigationAction" from the web process.

The following is the swift code used to load the page:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

let bookInfo = BookInfo.sharedInstance
let quizInfo = QuizInfo.sharedInstance

class AppendixViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let htmlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath:
            Bundle.main.path(
                forResource: quizInfo.questions[quizInfo.curQuiz][quizInfo.curQuestion[quizInfo.curQuiz]].appendix,
                ofType: "html",
                inDirectory: "Bookshelf/Books/" + bookInfo.owned[bookInfo.bookSelected.ownedId].folder + bookInfo.owned[bookInfo.bookSelected.ownedId].version + "/quiz/appendix")!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.loadFileURL(htmlPath, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlPath)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension AppendixViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    // When page finishes loading then update ViewController title
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.title = webView.title
    }
}
```

The iframe is being loaded locally and is located outside of the html file's local root folder. I have this working perfectly fine in UIWebView, but doesn't seem to work when I migrate over to WKWebView. What am I doing wrong, or missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is not local website files and that this stuff is on a web server. You can change `"https://example.com"` to wherever you want it to point to.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //     Outlet For WebKitView On The View Controller
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webview.load(request)
    }

    //  This Will Hide the Status Bar On Iphone X
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops I should be clear. All files are local. Including the HTML included in the question.

Comment: I removed the 2 lines of whitespace which you had between each line of code. While some styles do put an extra line of whitespace between each line of code, two lines of whitespace between each line of code is excessive. Given that your whitespace really didn't vary, I just guessed as to where you you'd like to have actual breaks in your code. You're welcome to put the excess whitespace back it, but, frankly, I expect that most people will find it harder to read that way.